# req.files is empty when using multer in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to upload different types of files to server using multer in an express application. But every time server responds by stating TypeError: req.files is not iterable . I checked and req.files is empty.

Here is the code for the same:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('userfiles', 10);

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }

    let uploadedFiles = [];
    for (let item of req.files) {
      uploadedFiles.push({ filename: item.originalname });
    }

    // Everything went fine.
    res.json({ progress: 100, files: uploadedFiles });
  })
});

app.listen(8000, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('working on http://localhost:8000');
  }
})
```

And this is how I am calling this API from postman:
[Postman UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz7lo.png)

I am unable to figure out where the problem is. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran his code and he tried to store the images at the root of my filesystem.

to refer a a path relative to your current directory you need to use `./`

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')  // change 'upload/' to './uṕload'
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
  }
})
```

After this, the code worked.